# HTML Canvas is slow due to big amount of tiles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, html5-canvas

I'm looking for a solution or enhancement on my working script.

Basically i want to draw a color for each pixels of a 800*800 canvas.

It works but it is a bit laggy, the JS array containing all the tiles may be part of the problem but i think it's more the "redraw" of the canvas every time we move it.

I created a simplified fiddle for you. Try to drag the canvas multiple time to see the slowing.

https://jsfiddle.net/cndapbaq/7/

```
function draw(translatePos){
```

I tried different approch and this is the one that is the most performant, but still not enough..

Thanks for the help..

Comment: actually doesn't lag on my screen.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw You *might* have a faster PC though right?

Comment: don't you have a little delay ?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides true, that's also a possibility.

Comment: @Owow nope, i didnt. but here is a good link to optimizing canvas --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Optimizing_canvas.

Comment: Just draw to an offscreen canvas once then draw that canvas and you will have full frame rate 1/60th sec. Dont use jQuery when not needed its slow.... very slowwww.. Don't render from mouse events, it confuses the DOM and makes rendering slow. Use requestAnimationFrame to render